# Como usar Controlador en un vue.js?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js

me encontré este comentario relacionado al uso de vue.js pero en realidad no lo he podido hechar a andar 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en mi caso tengo el componente vue relacionado a la vista

este es mi controlador User.Controller

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en la vista "usuarios.blade" mando llamar mi componente ""
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y aqui "suariocomponent.vue"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y me marca este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Intenta con {{ $users }}

Comment: @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas temo que en el npm me marca lo siguiente cuando lo cambioa de {$users} a {{$users}}
ERROR in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib?{"cacheDirectory":true,"presets":[["env",{"modules":false,"targets":{"browsers":["> 2%"],"uglify":true}}]],"plugins":["transform-object-rest-spread",["transform-runtime",{"polyfill":false,"helpers":false}]]}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./resources/js/components/UsuarioComponent.vue
Module build failed: SyntaxError: C:/xampp/htdocs/admin/caja1/resources/js/components/UsuarioComponent.vue: Unexpected token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

encontré la respuesta y para esto basta con llamar a axios

```
let data1 =axios.get("api/user").then((response)=>{ this.users = response.data.users});
```

en donde `"axios.get"` es el metodo a utilizar `("api/user")`es la ruta del controlador , de preferencia tiene que estar en "API" y `then((response)=>{ this.users= response.data.users});`es la respuesta y donde quieres que se almacene, en mi caso la respuesta se guarda en "users",

a diferencia en lo que puse arriba de la declaracion de variables, en este caso tendra que ser de la siguiente manera:

```
data(){
        return {
           users: [],
      }
    },
```